# Building failed Erlang 17.3 on OpenBSD 5.6

Tags: erlang, bsd, openbsd

Trying build Erlang 17.3 on OpenBSD 5.6 with Kerl, but this crash with error:

```
=== Entering application erl_interface
gmake[3]: Entering directory '/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/lib/erl_interface/src'
 MAKE   opt
gmake[4]: Entering directory '/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/lib/erl_interface/src'
x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.6/Makefile:39: amd64-unknown-openbsd5.6/eidefs.mk: No such file or directory
gmake[4]: *** No rule to make target 'amd64-unknown-openbsd5.6/eidefs.mk'.  Stop.
gmake[4]: Leaving directory '/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/lib/erl_interface/src'
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'opt' failed
gmake[3]: *** [opt] Error 2
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/lib/erl_interface/src'
/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/make/otp_subdir.mk:28: recipe for target 'opt' failed
gmake[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/lib/erl_interface'
/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/make/otp_subdir.mk:28: recipe for target 'opt' failed
gmake[1]: *** [opt] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/motiv/.kerl/builds/v17.3/otp_src_17.3/lib'
Makefile:451: recipe for target 'libs' failed
gmake: *** [libs] Error 2
```

Any know what fix this bug?

Comment: It looks like part of the build system canonicalises the host type to `x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.6`, while another part leaves it as `amd64-unknown-openbsd5.6`.  You could try defining `KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--build=x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.6"` to make it consistent.

Comment: Thanks. With "TARGET=x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.6 kerl build 17.3 v17.3" this error is resolved, but not build(new trouble): [link](http://pastebin.com/NUcwq5ui)

Comment: Looks like a missing include directive, or something.  You might get a quicker response by writing to [the erlang-bugs mailing list](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs); there was a post by an OpenBSD user there recently.

Comment: [This pull request](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/557), submitted a few days ago, seems to address this error.

Answer (score 0):

How did you invoke the build? With ./otp_build all? I have succeeded in building on OpenBSD 5.5 by invoking ./otp_build one step at a time, i.e., ./otp_build autoconf; ./otp_build configure; ./otp_build boot; ./otp_build release